# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 makes floating point calculations more accurate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have the following test cases in xUnit.

```
Assert.NotEqual(0f, 0.1f + 0.2f - 0.3f);
Assert.NotEqual(0d, 0.1d + 0.2d - 0.3d);
Assert.Equal(0m, 0.1m + 0.2m - 0.3m);
```

They had been working well for years across VS 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015 on .NET 4 or 4.5. The results were the same with MS Test. The test cases are to prove floating calculations may not be precise enough. since 0.1+0.2 is expected to be 0.30000000000000004.

However, today, I found that the first case is broken, obviously the .NET runtime and compiler consider 0.1f+0.2f==0.3f. I am not sure this is related to that I upgraded to VS 2015 Update 2 a few days ago. I then try the same tests in VS 2012 Update 4, the first test case is OK. I would suspect that .NET compiler of VS 2015 update 2 is broken or is making floating point calculation more accurate. The results are consistent across .NET 4, 4.5 and 4.6.1 as long as being compiled by VS 2015 update 2. I am not entirely sure this is a bug of VS 2015 update 2, or is a good thing? Do you have some idea?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the runtime, given that all the expressions are constant expressions. I suggest you have a look at the IL generated.

Comment: Tends to wise to only test the code that you can actually fix.  You'll have to click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Comment: Why would you even have these test cases? You don't have to test the language itself.

Comment: @Rolfツ this is clearly a complicated issue in his code and this was the minimum test that showed the problem

Comment: Neil Gafter and I did some fixes for floating point stuff for Roslyn 1.2. Not sure if this is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon, Hans and Hogan. Agree this is likely the compiler issue since I had written a compiler over 20 years ago. And I have reported the issue as suggested, at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11311  with the following test cases.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFloatConst()
    {
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0f, 0.1f + 0.2f - 0.3f);//Broken in VS 2015 Update 2
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFloatConstComparison()
    {
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0.3f, 0.1f + 0.2f);//Broken in VS 2015 Update 2
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDoubleConst()
    {
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0d, 0.1d + 0.2d - 0.3d);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDoubleConstComparison()
    {
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0.3d, 0.1d + 0.2d);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDecimalConst()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0m, 0.1m + 0.2m - 0.3m);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFloatVariable()
    {
        var a = 0.1f;
        var b = 0.2f;
        var c = 0.3f;
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0f, a+b-c);//OK in both debug and release builds
    }
```

Comment: According to the responses in the issue, apparently this is a new feature though not specified in the specifications.